# Javascript set value by document ID

Tags: javascript, document, setvalue

What I would like to do is if there is clicked at the 'reset' button, the value of a other button changes. I tried to use the document.getelementbyid property but it seems not to work. Does somebody know how I should implement this?

```
function reset() {
    stop();
    x.reset();
    update();
    opnieuw = setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("scherm3").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
     }, 10000);    
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    clearTimeout(timeOutElse);
    document.getElementById("buttontimer").value = "Start";
} 

setTimeout(start, 5000);

function toggleTimer(event) {
 if (isTimerStarted) {
    stop();
    event.target.value = 'Start';
    timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("scherm4").style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
     }, 4000)
    clearTimeout(opnieuw);
    clearTimeout(timeOutElse);
    }
     else {
    start();
    event.target.value = 'Stop';
    timeOutElse = setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("scherm3").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 8000)
          clearTimeout(timeOut);
    clearTimeout(opnieuw);
  }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="button1"><input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="toggleTimer(event); clicks5times();" id="buttontimer"></div>       
        <input type="button" value="Opnieuw" onclick="reset()" class="button2" id="opnieuw">
```

Comment: And what's your html?

Comment: you've got a reset function which is never called, a setTimeout on a start function which is not defined, and a toggleTimer function which is never called.  You might get helpful answers if you post everything you have and describe what you want it to do that it is not doing.

Comment: @EvertonAgner I edit my post!

Comment: @MarkEvaul I can do that, but there's a lot more functions and I guess you will not see the problem. The only thing that I want to do, is the change the value when there is clicked at 'Reset'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just make your code simpler by simply having a "Start" and "Stop" button, separately, and just show/hide the correct button for the current context.  You are already (sort of) doing this, by showing the "Reset" button.  Just make this a "Stop" button.  When they click "Start", the "Start" button is hidden and the "Stop" button is shown.  Click "Stop", and "Stop" is hidden and "Start" is shown.  You could even use a global boolean to track state and make the "Stop" button behave like a "Pause" button, and show an additional "Reset" button that puts the timer back to 0.  That all depends on what, exactly, you are trying to accomplish.